# What is the longest sequence of consecutive captures in a FIDE rated game?

Tags: fide, records, captures

What is the longest sequence of consecutive captures (including both pawn captures and piece captures) in a FIDE rated game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Tim Krabbé](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/recordstxt.htm#Longest%20capturing%20series), the record is 17 moves and it's tied between the following games:

- [Blodig - Wimmer, Germany 1988](http://homepage.eircom.net/%7Ereidr1/Capture.htm)

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "23"]
[Site "Germany"]
[Date "1988"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Blodig"]
[Black "Wimmer"]

1.g3 e5 2.Bg2 d5 3.d3 Nf6 4.Nf3 Nc6 5.O-O h6 6.c3 Be6 7.Nbd2 Qd7 8.b4 a6 9.a4 Bd6 10.Bb2 O-O 11.b5 Na5 12.c4 dxc4 13.dxc4 Nxc4 14.Nxc4 Bxc4 15.Nxe5 Bxe5 16.Bxe5 Qxd1 17.Rfxd1 axb5 18.Bxb7 Rxa4 19.Rxa4 bxa4 20.Bxc7 Bxe2 21.Rd4 Re8 22.Bd6 Rd8 23.Be5 Rxd4 24.Bxd4 a3 25.f3 a2 26.Kf2 Bc4 27.Bc6 Nh7 28.h4 Nf8 29.Ba4 Ne6 30.Ba1 Nc5 31.Bc2 Bb3 32.Bf5 g6 33.Bh3 Be6 34.Bxe6 fxe6 35.Ke3 Nb3 0-1
```

- [Rudd - Roberson, British ch, Swansea 2006](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1426259)

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "British Championship"]
[Site "Swansea WLS"]
[Date "2006.08.11"]
[EventDate "2006.08.07"]
[Round "5"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[White "Jack Rudd"]
[Black "Peter T Roberson"]
[ECO "A65"]
[WhiteElo "2328"]
[BlackElo "2122"]
[PlyCount "288"]
[StartPly "29"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5 e6 4. Nc3 exd5 5. cxd5 d6 6. e4 g6
7. Nge2 Bg7 8. Ng3 O-O 9. Be2 Na6 10. O-O Nc7 11. Bg5 Re8
12. Qd2 a6 13. a4 Bd7 14. f4 b5 15. e5 dxe5 16. fxe5 Rxe5
17. axb5 Bxb5 18. Bxb5 Nxb5 19. Nxb5 axb5 20. Rxa8 Qxa8
21. Bxf6 Bxf6 22. Rxf6 Qxd5 23. Qxd5 Rxd5 24. Ne4 Re5 25. Nc3
b4 26. Na4 c4 27. Rb6 c3 28. bxc3 bxc3 29. Nxc3 Re7 30. Kf2
Kg7 31. Kf3 h5 32. Ne4 Ra7 33. Rb3 Re7 34. g3 Ra7 35. Nd6 Ra6
36. Ne8+ Kf8 37. Rb8 Ke7 38. Nc7 Ra5 39. Nb5 Ra2 40. h4 Ra1
41. Rb7+ Ke6 42. Nd4+ Kf6 43. Kg2 Ra2+ 44. Kh3 Rf2 45. Rb3 Kg7
46. Nf3 Ra2 47. Ng5 Ra7 48. Kg2 Re7 49. Kf3 Ra7 50. Rb4 Re7
51. Ne4 Ra7 52. Nd6 Ra6 53. Rd4 Ra1 54. Rf4 Ra3+ 55. Kg2 Ra2+
56. Rf2 Ra7 57. Rb2 Ra6 58. Ne4 Ra7 59. Kf3 Re7 60. Kf4 Kg8
61. Nd6 Re6 62. Rb8+ Kg7 63. Ne8+ Kh6 64. Rd8 Re7 65. Nd6 Kg7
66. Re8 Ra7 67. Rb8 Ra4+ 68. Ke5 Ra5+ 69. Rb5 Ra3 70. Rb7 Rf3
71. Ne4 Re3 72. Kd4 Re1 73. Ng5 Rf1 74. Ke5 Kf8 75. Kd6 Rd1+
76. Kc7 Rc1+ 77. Kd8 Rd1+ 78. Rd7 Rf1 79. Ne4 Ra1 80. Nd6 Rf1
81. Re7 Rf2 82. Re4 Rd2 83. Kd7 Ra2 84. g4 hxg4 85. Rxg4 Kg7
86. Rf4 Ra7+ 87. Kc6 Re7 88. Kd5 f5 89. Ra4 Kf6 90. Ra6 Kg7
91. h5 Re1 92. hxg6 Kxg6 93. Ne4+ Kg7 94. Ng3 Rb1 95. Nxf5+
Kf7 96. Ke5 Re1+ 97. Kf4 Rf1+ 98. Ke5 Re1+ 99. Kd5 Rd1+
100. Nd4 Ke7 101. Re6+ Kf7 102. Re2 Ra1 103. Kd6 Ra6+ 104. Nc6
Ra1 105. Ne5+ Kf6 106. Rf2+ Kg5 107. Ke6 Ra6+ 108. Kf7 Ra7+
109. Kg8 Ra8+ 110. Kg7 Ra7+ 111. Nf7+ Kg4 112. Rf6 Rb7
113. Kg6 Kg3 114. Nd6 Ra7 115. Kg5 Ra5+ 116. Nf5+ Kf3 117. Re6
Rb5 118. Re3+ Kf2 119. Ra3 Rb4 120. Ne3 Rb5+ 121. Kh4 Rb4+
122. Kh3 Rb8 123. Nf5 Rh8+ 124. Kg4 Rg8+ 125. Kf4 Ke2 126. Rc3
Kd2 127. Rc7 Kd3 128. Ke5 Re8+ 129. Kd5 Rd8+ 130. Nd6 Rh8
131. Nf7 Rh5+ 132. Ne5+ Ke3 133. Rc2 Rh8 134. Rc3+ Kd2
135. Rg3 Rd8+ 136. Ke4 Re8 137. Rd3+ Kc2 138. Rd5 Rh8 139. Nf3
Re8+ 140. Kd4 Rg8 141. Rc5+ Kb3 142. Kd3 Rg3 143. Rf5 Rh3
144. Rf4 Rg3 1/2-1/2
```